# OSGi : Bundle Activation

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

Conceptually, what does it mean to “activate a bundle” in OSGi (e.g. what operations are done on a bundle to activate it). What happens, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the bundle has a [BundleActivator](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator.html) then the start method of it is called.

Frameworks like declarative services might also watch the bundle status and activate components declared in the bundle.